# Rudin, theorem 2.30 intuition behind

Tags: real-analysis

could you show 1-2 real examples that is related to this theorem?

2.30 Theorem: Suppose ⊂. A subset  of  is open relative to  if and only if =∩ for some open subset  of .

Comment: Picture your metric space as a piece of dough. Some parts of that dough are what we call open sets. Now you take a biscuit cutter and cut out part of the dough; this cut-out part is your new metric space. Which parts of this new metric space are open sets? Precisely the parts that were cut from the originally open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\mathbb{R}=Y\subset X=\mathbb{R}^2$. Then any open set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is given by a countable union of open intervals, $\Omega=\bigcup_{j\in J}(a_j,b_j)$.

Each $(a_j,b_j)$ can be rewritten as $B\left(\frac{a_j+b_j}{2},\frac{b_j-a_j}{2}\right)\cap \mathbb{R}$, i.e. a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius half the length of the interval, centered at the middle of the interval?

Then,
$$
E=\bigcup_{j\in J}(a_j,b_j)=\bigcup_{j\in J}B\left(\frac{a_j+b_j}{2},\frac{b_j-a_j}{2}\right)\cap \mathbb{R}\\
=\mathbb{R}\cap\bigcup_{j\in J}B\left(\frac{a_j+b_j}{2},\frac{b_j-a_j}{2}\right)
$$
and $G=\bigcup_{j\in J}B\left(\frac{a_j+b_j}{2},\frac{b_j-a_j}{2}\right)$.

It might be fun to try the above out on $\mathbb{R}^k\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $k<n$.

Comment: Thanks, besides I wonder. if $A$ is open relative to $B$, does this mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$? I guess yes, right?

Comment: Yes, $A$ should be a subset of $B$, but it could be all of $B$